# arranging images inside a div automatically without leaving any white space when another image is enlarged

Tags: jquery, html

I have a div full of images of the same size.
And when i click on an image it is enlarged by 300% of its previous size.
What i want to do is that i dont want to leave any white space on my image container div.
It is working fine for the images in left column, but when i click on an image other than the left column it leaves white space.

This is the original view before zooming.

[image: This is how images appear in the start]

[image: When i scaled the first image it worked perfectly fine]

[image: But when i scale any image which is not in the left column it appears like this i don't want the white space]

The Code i am using is
    Jquery

```
$(".light-box-items").click(function(){
            $("#"+zoomedImage).animate({"height":"200px" , "width":"25%"},400);
            $(this).animate({"height":"600px" , "width":"75%"},400);
            zoomedImage = this.id;
    });
```

css

```
#light-box{
position:absolute;
right:-93%;
min-height:100%;
height:auto;
width:80%;
background-color:grey;}
.light-box-items
{
    height:200px;
    width:25%;
    background-color:red;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: can you make a fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sheikhawais/hurjqLhq/2/

Comment: when I click on an enlarged element It do not turn to small size...

Comment: i tried different ways.but no luck. its seems like you need to handle the positioning via javascript for elements (`just a way`) on click event.